# C# reference pointer

Tags: c#

```
using System;

public class Class1 {
     public int A {get;set;}    
}

public class Class2 {
    public Class1 class1 {get;set;} 
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Class1 c1 = null;
        var c2 = new Class2();
        c2.class1 = c1;

        c1 = new Class1();
        c1.A = 1;

        Console.WriteLine(c2.class1.A); //Expect 1 not NULL ref err
    }
}
```

I would expect that the `c2` object would get its `class1` reference updated because its passing by reference, so the reference was updated but it remained null.

When you set c2.class1 = c1  and c1 is currently null does it keep the the value `null` and not use a pointer to the empty memory space?

Comment: What your code is doing is kind of creating a copy of the `c1` variable and storing it in `c2.class1`. Then, when you update `c1` and set it to `new Class1();`, you aren't affecting `c2.class1` at all. You would need to do `c2.class1 = new Class1();` to do this.

Comment: Your question is answered by running the code and seeing what it does?  When you ran the code, what happened?

Comment: ‘C1’ and ‘c2.class1’ are two separate references.  They need not refer to the same object, and changing one doesn’t change the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `c1 = new Class1();` that `c1` points to a *new* instance of your Class1. 
The old reference in c1 is replaced by a new one, to that new instance.

That you previously used the old value of c1 to set `c2.class1` is not remembered. That c2.class1 keeps its old value.